# The version of ...\WinSCP.exe does not match version of this assembly when using WinSCP .NET assemly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, winscp, winscp-net

I'm using a library called `WinSCPnet.dll`. The code will only work if I set the `AssemblyFileVersion` to the same version as the `WinSCP.exe` where it is installed.

I got this exception:

> The version of C:\Program Files (x86l\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe
>       (5.15.1.0) does not match version of this assembly
>       C:\Users\burkarty\source\repos\UAReport3\UAReport3\bin\Debug\UAReport3.exe (0.0.0.0).

How can I run my code independent from the WinSCP version?

I searched for a similar question but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not rely on *installed version of WinSCP*.

Your application should deploy its own copy of `WinSCP.exe`, which application's version of `WinSCPnet.dll` is compatible with. Ideally, use [WinSCP NuGet package](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#nuget), which takes care of that.

For other options, see [WinSCP .NET assembly installation and deployment instructions](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install).